# AWS S3 Golang SDK - uploading files - wrong region

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to upload a file to S3 via the official Golang AWS SDK.

I'm targeting a bucket that's specified to be in Northern California region (us-west-1). I can see it in the S3 explorer; however, when I run the put operation I get the following error:

```
BucketRegionError: incorrect region, the bucket is not in 'Northern California' region
```

This is how I am setting up my connection:

```
creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, token)
_,err := creds.Get()

config := &aws.Config{
    Region          :aws.String("us-west-1"),
    Endpoint        :aws.String("s3.amazonaws.com"),
    S3ForcePathStyle:aws.Bool(true),
    Credentials     :creds,
    //LogLevel        :0,
}

s3_client := s3.New(session.New(config))

params := &s3.PutObjectInput{
    Bucket       :aws.String(p_bucket_name_str),         
    Key          :aws.String(p_target_file__s3_path_str),
    ACL          :aws.String("public-read"),
    Body         :file_bytes,
    ContentLength:aws.Int64(size),
    ContentType  :aws.String(file_type),
    Metadata     :map[string]*string{
         "Key":aws.String("MetadataValue"),
    },
}

result,err := p_s3_client.PutObject(params)
```

Any suggestion or fix would be of huge help, thank you.

Comment: Are you really, really sure your bucket is in us-west-1?

Comment: In the AWS web tool dashboard for the bucket, its telling me North California... I checked in Amazons tables, and North California maps to us-west-1. Thats also the region thats in the URL pattern when accessing bucket files via the web browser...

Comment: I have tried us-west-1,us-west-2,us-east-1 regions, and all three return the same response "BucketRegionError: incorrect region, the bucket is not in 'us-west-1' region" (region being us-west-1/us-west-2/us-east-1)

Comment: I still believe you make some mistake in looking up the buckets location in the web tool. As a first step i would check the buckets location in your go code by GetBucketLocation.

Comment: You can verify the region via curl for any bucket with the command: curl -I "https://<bucket_name>.s3.amazonaws.com"  The returned header, "x-amz-bucket-region" will state the region the bucket is in.

Answer (score 2):

the `aws-sdk-go` offers a [s3manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager.html) tool to make this work more convenient. You can upload a file like below:

```
creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(AccessKey, SecretKey, "")
sess := session.New(&aws.Config{
    Credentials: creds,
    Region:      &Region,
})

uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)
uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
    ACL:         aws.String(acl),
    Bucket:      aws.String(bucket),
    Key:         aws.String(key),
    ContentType: aws.String(contentType),
    Body:        r,
})
```

Comment: Ive triend this method today, and while it does reduce the amount of code needed, it still returns the same error response. :(

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing this error because you think your bucket exists in `us-west-1` region, and your request is being made to the `us-east-1` region. For the AWS SDK for Go the endpoint `s3.amazon.com` maps to the `us-east-1` region.

Use the curl command `curl -I "https://<bucketname>.s3.amazonaws.com"` to verify the region your bucket is actually in with the header `x-amz-bucket-region`

Once you have the correct region remove the `Endpoint` value from your config your request should start working. The SDK will determine the endpoint URL automatically based on the region provided. The `Endpoint` value is overriding the URL the SDK would look up for the service.

The SDK does not automatically switch regions and resend the request when the request was made to the `s3.amazon.com` endpoint when the bucket exists in a different region.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of end-point. End-point "`s3.amazonaws.com`" is for `us-east-1` region by default. If you want to create bucket for `us-west-1` you have to put end-point as "`s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com`"